# Backup auto awesomed photos and videos from Google Plus/Google Photos?

Tags: backup, photos, google-plus

I have set my Android phone to automatically upload my images to Google Photo and Dropbox for backup. In addition I routinely (once a week or so) copy all the images to my computer.

I use my local computer(s) to actually watch/show the photos (and the images are stored together with images from my SLR camera and my wife's phone).

I really like Google's auto awesome feature, but it's such a hassle to manually download them to my phone or computer to show them off.

Is there a way to automatically download my images from Google Photos?

I've seen similar questions here before, where the only answer is the Picasa desktop application. As far as I can see, Picasa is not able to automatically download pictures from Google Photos that where originally automatically backed up from my phone.

I can manually download them with Picasa, but no auto download.

Any other suggestions?

As I said, I'm really just interested in the auto awesome photos, as I already have all the other photos on my computer, but I guess I'm more likely to find a solution that downloads all new photos from Google Photos.

**UPDATE June 10th 2015 - Issue finally resolved by Google**

Finally, Google has merged Google Photos and Google Drive. Now it works like I wanted it to, where the folder on my computer is completely in sync with the gallery online and on my phone, *including* auto awesome photos and videos.

Comment: I just realised Picasa doesn't download videos at all (and the auto awesome videos are the best part of auto awesome), so Picasa is completely out of the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems it's only possible to download the auto awesome photos and videos manually. None of the applications I've tested that uses Google's API are able to download the "Auto Backup" album.

The easiest way to download the auto awesomed images is this:

1. Go to Google Photos and search for #AutoAwesome: https://plus.google.com/u/0/photos/search/%23AutoAwesome
2. Select the new auto awesome pictures by selecting the first one, then holding down SHIFT and selecting the last one
3. Open the "More" menu at the top
4. Select "Download"

My strategy at the moment is to do this about once a week.

Hopefully Google will open the auto backup album through it's API soon, but in the meantime this will have to do.

Answer (score 0):

Auto download from Google using Google Drive has a Sync App similar to what Dropbox has.

Comment: I'm not sure how this is helpful. Can I get my Google Photos synced with Google Drive somehow? I haven't found any way to use the Google Drive sync app to download anything outside Google Drive.